# gsoap error: HTTP internal server error: End of file or no input: Operation interrupted or timed out (5 s recv delay)

Tags: web-services, soap, gsoap, soapfault, http-status-code-500

I have implemented a webservice using gsoap c++, problem is i am getting a random 500 internal error with fault code as "End of file or no input: Operation interrupted or timed out". 
 with this i have verified the total time of request. All is validated within a matter of milli seconds.
 also, i verified one successful response with the problmetic one, all the xml values are identical.
 can any one suggest where i might be doing wrong?

following is chunk debug logs from SENT.log created by GSOAP server

<ResponseCode>00</ResponseCode><pDateTime>12055229</pDateTime><R1>null</R1><R2>null</R2><R3>null</R3><R4>null</R4>
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: gSOAP/2.8
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 456
Connection: close

SOAP-ENV:ClientEnd of file or no input: Operation interrupted or timed out (5 s recv delay)HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: gSOAP/2.8
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 456
Connection: close"

Answer (score 0):

Your timeout setting is perhaps too low (only 5 seconds), which means that the connection times out if no data was received within 5 seconds. Set `soap->recv_timeout = 30` which increases the data receive timeout to 30 seconds. It depends on your application what timeout settings are acceptable, but 5 seconds is definitely tight.